# Cómo desplegar una aplicación WAR SpringBoot en Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, maven

tengo un proyecto que realice con Springboot Maven ahora estoy intentando deployar el 
WAR en un server con TOMCAT 8.0.23 jdk 8.0_60 pero en el proceso siguientes lineas para que al finalizar muestre error, es la primera vez que trabajo con esta tecnologia y no logro comprender cual es el problema lo estoy deployando en un hosting compartido que me proporciona NGASI para la administración del AppServer.

```
30-May-2020 23:16:03.841 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.5.RELEASE)

2020-05-30 23:16:05.184  INFO 59160 --- [ost-startStop-1] i.b.s.f.IsasapifacturacionApplication    : Starting IsasapifacturacionApplication on etacarinae.e-novanet.mx with PID 59160 (/home/isasclou/appservers/apache-tomcat-8x/webapps/isasapifacturacion/WEB-INF/classes/isasapi/bo/springboot/facturacion/IsasapifacturacionApplication.class started by isasclou in /home/isasclou/appservers/apache-tomcat-8x)
2020-05-30 23:16:05.192  INFO 59160 --- [ost-startStop-1] i.b.s.f.IsasapifacturacionApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-05-30 23:16:06.229  INFO 59160 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-05-30 23:16:06.319  INFO 59160 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 79ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-05-30 23:16:06.736  INFO 59160 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1475 ms
2020-05-30 23:16:07.338  INFO 59160 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-05-30 23:16:07.756  INFO 59160 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
2020-05-30 23:16:07.974  INFO 59160 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-05-30 23:16:08.199  INFO 59160 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-05-30 23:16:08.425  INFO 59160 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-05-30 23:16:08.448  INFO 59160 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: Puede que este hilo te ayude, el usuario tiene un problema parecido al tuyo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905001/at-least-one-jar-was-scanned-for-tlds-yet-contained-no-tlds

Comment: y cual es el error, porque en lo que colocas no veo uno.

Comment: Tuve el mismo problema, sin embargo realice pruebas con las versiones de Tomcat 8.5.40 y 8.5.56 con JDK 1.8.0251 y el archivo war deploya sin ningún problema.

Comment: Deploya? _Despliega_.  :)

Comment: @EdgarGc eso no es un error. Ese es un comportamiento estándar de Tomcat, que escanea los JAR que uno incluya (o no) según se le configure.

Comment: La mala costumbre al expresar el despliegue :).